Is it impossible to overwrite a 0byte file on NFS?
I have set up NFS using AWS Storage Gateway and File Share on a Mac environment. When using a specific program to create 0byte files on this NFS, if a file with the same name already exists, the program does not overwrite it but instead retains the existing file.
For example:

Create a.txt at 12:35 pm
Create a.txt at 12:40 pm
The system information for a.txt shows the last modification time as 12:35 pm.

Is it impossible to overwrite 0byte files on NFS? My main question is that when performing the same action locally, the mtime changes correctly. Why is there this difference?
I tried changing various NFS mount options and also made adjustments to the S3 settings, but I was not able to achieve the desired result.

You say “when performing the same action locally, the mtime changes correctly.”  I would argue that that is incorrect behavior.  If 0 bytes of data are written, mtime shouldn’t be changed.  But this would be clearer if you described exactly what you are doing.  Are you using a standard, existing command like cp or dd?  Did you write your own code (e.g., in C)?

I am not using commands or source code directly. I am using the Unity engine, and during the build process, the MovedFromExtractor application within Unity extracts and updates API changes, resulting in the creation of 0-byte DLL files. I don't know how this application works or its source code, but as mentioned in the question, when the same file is created with MovedFromExtractor, the mtime is updated locally, but not on NFS.

Overwriting a 0 byte file probably shouldn't change the file's mtime, but deleting it and creating a new 0 byte file will.  Have you examined the file's stat() info on the NFS server to be sure it's not a new file?  ("on the NFS server" is an important detail)

In your example, are the "old" and "new" a.txt files both 0 bytes, or just one of them?

They are all 0 bytes.

If you want to retain the inode, permissions, etc, of the original file, you can append a single byte to it, and then truncate it to zero bytes again. That can be done in shell or C. touch is also useful (and I suspect it does this same technique).

The most likely reason is that the "specific program" does not work as you expect. That NFS is involved is not relevant. It is possible (although unlikely) that this is an issue in the storage gaetway.
